# Error message on simplexml_load_file()

Tags: php

I am new to PHP functions and trying to use the simplexml_load_file() to read an xml file in my terminal but getting an error as stated below my code.  I don't know if this makes a difference or not but I'm running on the mac os x OS, Mountain Lion and the xml file is sitting in a directory on my local box.  Any suggestions/direction would be greatly appreciated.  Regards.

Here is the function:

```
function xmlFileLoader($sourceDir) {

// Properties
$sourceXmlDir = scandir($sourceDir);
$count_xml_files = count($sourceXmlDir);

// Removes any directory or file other than XML file from the contents of the $sourceDir variable:
for( $i = 0; $i < $count_xml_files; $i++ ) {
    $path_info = pathinfo( $sourceXmlDir[$i] );

    if( preg_match( '/^\./', $sourceXmlDir[$i] ) || is_dir( $sourceXmlDir . '/' . $sourceXmlDir[$i] ) || ( strtoupper( $path_info['extension'] ) <> 'XML' ) )
    {
        unset( $sourceXmlDir[$i] );
    }
}

// Get the correct count of the values in the $sourceXmlDir after the unset function completes
$sourceXmlArray = array_values($sourceXmlDir);
$count_xml_files = count($sourceXmlArray);

if ($count_xml_files > 0) {

    // Cycle through the XML files in the $sourceXmlArray
    foreach ($sourceXmlArray as $xmlFile) {

        $sFile = simplexml_load_file($xmlFile);

        print_r($sFile);
    }
}
```

}

The error that I'm getting is as follows in my terminal:

PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "sfly-6x8.000020513524-7001536_28935-tb.33.xml" in /Users/msavoy/Sites/TestScripts/xmlFileLoader.php on line 47

Warning: simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "sfly-6x8.000020513524-7001536_28935-tb.33.xml" in /Users/msavoy/Sites/TestScripts/xmlFileLoader.php on line 47

When I do a var_dump on the $xmlFile I get the correct file name:  sfly-6x8.000020513524-7001536_28935-tb.33.xml

So I'm not sure what the problem is.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that I needed to define the FULL PATH in the simplexml_load_file($xmlFile) method.  I just had to keep on looking.

Sorry.

Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your php.ini file, probably this method be deactivated. Remember simplexml_load_file() just work in PHP 5.

Comment: I'm running on PHP 5.4.  But I'll check anyway.  Thanks.